# Remove Yellow Squares Created by the LRS Plug-in

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing, mapcanvas

Does anyone know how I can remove the yellow squares which appear in my QGIS project when using the "Locate" tool within the "LRS" Plug-in?

I have refreshed the Project and also can't deselect them! They are also apparent on the screen if I turn all the layers off.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with the provider of the plugin and their tutorial?

Comment: Hi Erik, I have been through the tutorial with no luck, and can't find any contact details for them.

Comment: I don't know the plugin, and you say you cannot deslect them. However, features appear yellow in QGIS when selected. Try to de-select all features using Ctrl-Alt-A and see if this persists.

Comment: Hi Leigh, Unfortunately the yellow squares are not related to features, but are markers the Plug-in creates to show a position on the screen. The squares are not held within any layer, as if I turn all layers off the squares are still evident.

Comment: Update - even if a new / blank project is created the yellow squares are still evident. The only way I have found to clear the screen of the squares to close and restart QGIS.
Not sure if this information helps anyone shed some light on this issue!

Comment: I have the exact same problem now. Did you ever find a way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! I never did find a way to resolve this issue!